# ArangoDB AQL Non Case Sensitive Comparison

Tags: case-sensitive, arangodb, aql

Let's imagine I have a few simple docs stored in an Arango collection like so:

```
[
    {"type":Cat, "quality":Fuzzy}
    {"type":Dog, "quality":Barks}
    {"type":Rabbit, "quality":Hoppy}
    {"type":Pig, "quality":Chubby}
    {"type":Red Panda, "quality":Fuzzy}
    {"type":Monkey, "quality":Hairy}
]
```

Now let's say a user initiates a search in my application for all animals that are 'fuzzy', all lower case. Is there a way with AQL to make a comparison that is not case sensitive? So for instance:

```
FOR a IN animals
    FILTER a.type.toLowerCase() == fuzzy
    RETURN a
```

Now I know the above example doesn't work, but it would be nice if there was a way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a `LOWER` string function in AQL which you can try to use in your query like this:

```
FOR a IN animals
    FILTER LOWER(a.quality) == 'fuzzy'
    RETURN a
```

Comment: Great I was hoping for something like that! Can u show me where the documentation is for this? I couldn't find it.

Comment: The AQL functions documentation is here: https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/Aql.html#AqlFunctions